# Materializecss Modal on page load not open the modal

Tags: modal-dialog, materialize

I use Materializecss 0.100.2 and i need to open a modal on page load or document ready. But not work, it will be work only if i click on button, i don't know why.
The modal has class "open" but the modal have "display: none" and the div modal-overlay is hidden. It work but not completely.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 jQuery('#modalInfo').modal();
 jQuery('#modalInfo').modal('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing works with vanillaJS. You need to get the modal class using `querySelector()` and then pass it in `M.Modal.init()`, and with the help of this `instance` you can call `open()` method.

HTML -

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS -

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
    var instanceModal = M.Modal.init(Modalelem);
    instanceModal.open();
});
```

Comment: Not working, i've this error :materialize.min.js?ver=4.9.8:6 Uncaught TypeError: e.each is not a function

Comment: From where you're getting `e.each` ?

Comment: Use latest version of Materialize @user3309614